# CFIF statements qualifying based on currentRow vs previous row value?

Tags: coldfusion, cfml

Attempting to create a page with tables on it and have ColdFusion create a new table based on a value in the returned query changing.

Data

```
pay_year  pay_period  bm_sold  sales 
2019      1           ABC      123   
2019      1           EFG      123
2019      1           HIJ      123
```

```
<cfset prevRep="">
            <cfset rowCount=#getCommReportB2Bitem.recordCount#>
            <cfdump var="#rowCount#">
            <cfloop query="getCommReportB2Bitem" startrow="1" endrow="#rowCount#">
            <div class="contentbox">
                <cfset curRep=#getCommReportB2Bitem.bm_sold#>
                <cfif curRep NEQ prevRep>
                <div class="panelheader"><cfoutput>B2B Report Results: Rep #getCommReportB2Bitem.bm_sold#, Pay Period #form.ppd#, #form.payyear#</cfoutput></div>


                <div class="panelcontent">
                    <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="paneltable tablesorter" id="reportTable1">
                        <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="paneltableheader">Year</th>
                            <th class="paneltableheader">PPD</th>
                            <th class="paneltableheader">BM</th>
                            <th class="paneltableheader">Part Div</th>
                            <th class="paneltableheader">Net Sales</th>
                            <th class="paneltableheader">Comm Rate</th>
                            <th class="paneltableheader">Commission</th>
                        </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                        <cfoutput query="getCommReportB2Bitem">
                        <tr>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#pay_year#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#pay_period#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#UCASE(bm_sold)#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#part_div#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#" align="right">#DollarFormat(sales)#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#" align="right">#NumberFormat(comm_rate * 100, "99.00")#%</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#" align="right">#DollarFormat(commission)#</td>


                        </tr>

                      <cfset prevRep=#bm_sold#>
                        </cfoutput>

                         </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
                        <cfelse>
                        <cfoutput query="getCommReportB2Bitem">

                        <tr>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#pay_year#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#pay_period#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#UCASE(bm_sold)#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#">#part_div#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#" align="right">#DollarFormat(sales)#</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#" align="right">#NumberFormat(comm_rate * 100, "99.00")#%</td>
                            <td class="#IIF(getCommReportB2Bitem.CurrentRow MOD 2, DE("paneltablecellodd"), DE("paneltablecell"))#" align="right">#DollarFormat(commission)#</td>


                        </tr>

                        <cfset prevRep=#bm_sold#>
                        </cfoutput>

                         </tbody>

                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
            </cfif>
            </cfloop>
```

Currently it appears to be looping over the query and starting new tables however after testing it seems it is outputting the first section over and over never reaching the "cfelse" as it should. Am I doing this correctly? Any better method to achieve this desired result?

EDIT -

Try to display desired output as best I can per comment.

```
Query data in:
    pay_year  pay_period  bm_sold  sales 
    2019      1           ABC      123   
    2019      1           EFG      789
    2019      1           EFG      123
    2019      1           HIJ      901    
    2019      1           HIJ      456

Desired Output:
   BM Sold: ABC
   Pay Year   Pay Period   Sales
   2019       1            123

   BM Sold: EFG
   Pay Year   Pay Period   Sales
   2019       1            789
   2019       1            123

   BM Sold: HIJ
   Pay Year   Pay Period   Sales
   2019       1            901
   2019       1            456
```

Comment: debug it. log the values at the point where they don't seem to be acting the way you expect it and compare them.

Comment: I will try and debug to see what is going on. This is possible correct to interrogate a value from the query results and use qualifying statements in this manner? I am slightly new to CF but applying how I know other things work as best I can...

Comment: well, depending on what the goal of this logic is, there might be easier ways to accomplish it through grouping.

Comment: Basically attempting to get a new table with header and all everytime the value in column bm_sold changes. The data in the code example at the top is what my query returns as one, then I was hoping based on that to display it in groups by the value in bm_sold. Seems like I am probably going about it the long way but made sense in my head as I wrote it.

Comment: Right. so what you do is ensure it's sorted by bm_sold, and then use the group attribute of cfloop on that column. the outerloop will be through the unique bm_sold values, and the inner loop will be through the rows that had that value. So the outerloop makes the tables, the inner loop makes the rows. no need to check cur row vs prev row. https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2359-coldfusion-10---using-the-group-attribute-with-cfloop-to-group-query-rows.htm

Comment: Interesting. I will have to read up on cfloop query and group, that may help to achieve this. Thanks Kevin

Comment: Kevin B has the right idea. If you need some tips, please dummy up an example of some sample data (with a few different scenarios - like no change, 2 changes, etc..) and what the output should look like.

Comment: Thanks Ageax I added an edit trying to show desired output. Hopefully clear enough, I can try and mock it up in CF if that would help too. Thanks again.

Comment: @KevinB Thank for pointing me in the right direction. I would happily mark answered if you'd like to post that link and comment.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see your comment, but it sounds like you figured it our? (Tip, add a `@` in front of the username to have S.O. auto notify them there's a new comment. :-) Unfortunately S.O. only notifies the author automatically...

Comment: Just in case, here's a rough example. https://trycf.com/gist/7690ae3e6bf1e443ce220064889b2a5e/acf2018?theme=monokai